# Error "initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite" using msm package in R

Tags: r

I am using R and the msm package (both for the first time) to model a process with a series of states.  I defined the initial transition matrix to indicate which instantaneous transitions are allowed and used 'gen.inits=True' as an argument in the msm function to have the model automatically generate initial values for the transition intensities using 'crudeinits'.  When I try running the model I get the error "initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite" and I'm not sure how to go about understanding (1) where the error is occurring and (2) how to fix it. I am looking for  some guidance as to how to go about debugging my code.

```
library(msm)

syr_set <- read.csv("Mergeset_Stages_Only.csv")

Q <- rbind(c(0.5,0.5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
           c(0,0.5,0.5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
           c(0,0,0.34,0.33,0.33,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
           c(0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
           c(0,0,0,0,0.5,0.5,0,0,0,0,0,0),
           c(0,0,0,0,0,0.5,0.5,0,0,0,0,0),
           c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0.5,0.5,0,0,0,0),
           c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.34,0.33,0.33,0,0),
           c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0),
           c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.5,0.5,0),
           c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.5,0.5),
           c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1))

syr.msm <- msm(Stage_Coded~Days, subject = PolicyNumber, 
               data = syr_set, qmatrix = Q, 
               gen.inits = TRUE, obstype=Obs_Type, 
               opt.method = "optim")
```

I noticed that when I passed the argument 'fixedpars=True' to the msm function, the model ran.  However, this fixes all the intensities in the initial Q matrix which is not what I want to do.